# How To Get The Value of an input field using AJAX and Pass it To A PHP String?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am new to JavaScript, so pardon my lack of knowledge.

I am trying to code a contact form and want to get the value entered in a particular input text field as soon as a value entered by the visitor using AJAX and pass it to a PHP string so that I can show relevant information based on the value entered before hitting the submit button.

How Can I do that **using jQuery**?

Here are the codes I am using for the form:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
<input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" />
<input type="text" id="url" name="url" />
<input type="checkbox" id="showdetails" name="showdetails" /> Show URL Details
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>`
```

I need the value of the URL input field to pass to a php string (as soon as the user checks the showdetails checkbok) so that I can process it in background to show information based on the url.

Comment: Using what? jQuery? mootools? native JS? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, jQuery. Sorry I didn't mentioned that. Edited my question and added that.

Comment: And do you want it _as soon as a value entered by the visitor_ or _(as soon as the user checks the showdetails checkbok)_ ??? There is a huge difference in user experience.

Comment: @mpungjan, as soon as the user checks the checkbox. Then it should check if any value entered in the field and pass it to a php string I could use in my functions. If no value is entered yet the box is checked, an error message pops up. Sorry, I am totally novice in JavaScript, so please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given this html:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
<input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" />
<input type="text" id="url" name="url" />
<input type="checkbox" id="showdetails" name="showdetails" /> Show URL Details
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

jQuery (checkbox)

```
$(function() {
  $("showdetails").on("click",function() {
    var url = $("#url").val();
    if (url && $(this).is(":checked")) {
      $.get("relevantinfo.php",
        { "url": url },
        function(data){
          // do something with data returned
        }
      );
    }
    else {
      // clear relevant info here
    }
  });
});
```

The receiving end: [Retrieving POST Data from AJAX Call to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236903/retrieving-post-data-from-ajax-call-to-php)

Comment: Consider using the `data` parameter of `$.get()` instead of building the query string manually.

Comment: Yes, but without the encoding. jQuery does that for you - that's why I suggested it.

Answer (score 3):

get the input string using **onchange** event in text field .

ref : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onchange

Then using that string content, call AJAX function.

```
function load(string) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "YOUR_URL", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

As suggested in the comments, use jquery + AJAX.
For jquery,

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/test.html',
    success: function(data) {
        $('.divClass').html(data);
        alert('Load was performed.');
    }
});
```

Comment: Instead of `XMLHttpRequest`, use jquery + Ajax to simplify

Comment: @LearneR jQuery is kinda big if you only use it for AJAX handling.

Comment: I suggest onclick of the checkbox rather than onchange since onchange needs a blur in some browsers

Comment: if jQuery is not already being used including the entire library to do XHR functions is overkill. Especially if dated browser support is not critical ([alternatives](http://microjs.com/#ajax)). I realize the OP asked for it, consider this a side comment.